# ByteArray issue with Actionscript project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to create a project for this library in FDT 5 IDE
I create a new project:

`File->New FDT Project->Web->AS3` then hit finish

Copied the files form here: https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js/tree/master/flash

However the IDE is showing problems in the project:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Could not resolve type reference to 'flash.utils.ByteArray' at line 576 column
25. MultipartURLLoader.as   /recorder/src/ru/inspirit/net   Unknown Flash Problem Could not resolve type reference to 'flash.utils.ByteArray' at line 581 column
39. MultipartURLLoader.as   /recorder/src/ru/inspirit/net   Unknown Flash Problem Incompatible types ByteArray and ByteArray. Found at line 184 column
37. MultipartURLLoader.as   /recorder/src/ru/inspirit/net   Unknown Flash Problem Incompatible types ByteArray and ByteArray. Found at line 447 column
24. MultipartURLLoader.as   /recorder/src/ru/inspirit/net   Unknown Flash Problem Unexpected Token playingProgressTimerHandler at line 103 column 69.   Recorder.as /recorder/src   Unknown Flash Problem Unexpected Token playingProgressTimerHandler at line 103 column
69. Recorder.as /recorder/src   Unknown Flash Problem Unexpected Token statusHandler at line 186 column
61. Recorder.as /recorder/src   Unknown Flash Problem Unexpected Token statusHandler at line 186 column
61. Recorder.as /recorder/src   Unknown Flash Problem Wrong number of arguments. Expect at least 2 but have found 1. Found at line 103 column 25.   Recorder.as /recorder/src   Unknown Flash Problem Wrong number of arguments. Expect at least 2 but have found 1. Found at line 186 column 15.   Recorder.as /recorder/src   Unknown Flash Problem You cannot assign 'ByteArray' to 'ByteArray'. Found 'fileContent;' at line 189 column
21. MultipartURLLoader.as   /recorder/src/ru/inspirit/net   Unknown Flash Problem You cannot assign 'ByteArray' to 'ByteArray'. Found 'fileContent;' at line 583 column
22. MultipartURLLoader.as   /recorder/src/ru/inspirit/net   Unknown Flash Problem
```

I'm really new to AS development and I just want to recompile sa said library.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to go through a FDT setup tutorial first. You'll require Flash Player 9+ for ByteArray class to be available, if I remember correctly. However, Flash Player 11 is your safest bet. Download Flex SDK and set it up using either of the following two tutorials:

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/2008/10/creating-flash-player-10-projects-with-fdt-beta/
http://www.applicationdomain.net/post/2008/05/26/Setting-up-FDT-for-Flash-Player-10

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried using mxlmc, it generates a SWF against the AS file however there are lots of warning and I am not sure if all the "dependencies" are compiled too?